# Migrate WordPress featured image into to Drupal content type

Tags: nodes, 8, migrations

I have a Drupal 8 site and I've installed the [WordPress Migrate](https://www.drupal.org/project/wordpress_migrate) module and its dependencies for migrating a WordPress site to Drupal 8.

All things are done and imported successfully with help of this [post](https://dev.acquia.com/blog/wordpress-drupal-8-migration). But I can't Import the featured images and map it to the image field in the Drupal site content type.

anyone have a solution for this?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you are working with Media Image Fields? Try it with core image field instead.